# php single use loop per database entry

Tags: php, loops, product

I don't have much experience when it comes to php, loops etc, but i copied this code from my page that im trying to load. It's a product page for a car dealership and I'm attempting to show each car in a table (I'm don't know enough CSS to do it that way) I've only been studying for 2 months.

With this code I am getting each car displayed as many times as there are entries within the database with a certain class.

I've taken out all the irrelevant stuff to make it easier to read, I hope someone can help I've been working on this project too long and thought I'd finally got it working when  I just ended up with 4 of each car in a row.

So far i have tried to put to use a `do-while` where do has an if statement calculation as to the value of $i which only ended up with undefined variable warning for `$title = [...]` as `Undefined Variable row in...`

What is the best thing to use to run a loop once per entry in a database?

Please excuse any mistyping, im exhausted.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $title = ("$row[year] "."$row[brand] ". "$row[model]");
    $uppic = $row['pic'];
    $picloc = "/upload/$uppic";
    $price = $row['price'];
    $stock = $row['stocknr'];
    for ($i = 1;$i <= $count; $i++)
    {
        if (($i == 1) or (($i - 1) % 4) == 0) {
            echo '<table><tr>' . "\n";
        }
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<br><a href='$des'>
          <span>$title</span></a>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<a href='$des'>
      <img src='$picloc'></a>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<br><a href=''>
  <span>$</span></a>";
        echo "</tr></table>";
        echo "</td>";

        // for 5th, 10th, 15th etc record 
        if ((($i) % 4) == 0) {
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
}
```

also tried this:

```
for ($i = 0;$i <= $count; $i++)
{
    $query = "SELECT year, brand, model, class, stocknr, price, status, pic 
    FROM stock WHERE class = 'car' ORDER BY brand ASC";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    do {
        $title = ("$row[year] "."$row[brand] ". "$row[model]");
        $uppic = $row['pic'];
        $picloc = "/upload/$uppic";
        $price = $row['price'];
        $stock = $row['stocknr'];
        if (($i == 1) or (($i - 1) % 4) == 0) {
            echo '<table><tr>' . "\n";
        }
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<br><a href='d.php?stocknr=$stock'>
          <span>$title</span></a>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<a href='d.php?stocknr=$stock'>
      <img src='$picloc'></a>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr >";
        echo "<br><a href='d.php?stocknr=$stock'>
  <span>R$p</span></a>";
        echo "</tr></table>";
        echo "</td>";

        // for 5th, 10th, 15th etc record
        if ((($i) % 4) == 0) {
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        while ($i <= $count); 
    }
```

only ended up with connection timeout on page load.

Comment: This `"$row[year] "."$row[brand] ". "$row[model]"` should be `"{$row['year']} {$row['brand']} {$row['model']}"`

Comment: That line didn't give me any problems, it producted the title, picture and price without problems, but thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it works but only because PHP assumes that when you wrote `year` you meant `'year'` etc. If you enable notices and warnings by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` to the beginning of your code you will see the messages.

Comment: That's weird, I Have Error reporting enabled, I will keep it in mind though , at the moment my biggest problem is syntax error, deciding between `'` and `"` as an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$i = 1;
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{

    $title = ("$row[year] "."$row[brand] ". "$row[model]");
    $uppic = $row['pic'];
    $picloc = "/upload/$uppic";
    $price = $row['price'];
    $stock = $row['stocknr'];

    if($i%4==1) echo "<tr>";

        echo "<td>";
            echo "<table>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<br><a href='$des'><span>$title</span></a>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<a href='$des'><img src='$picloc'></a>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<br><a href=''><span>$</span></a>";
                echo "</tr></table>";
        echo "</td>";

    if($i%4==0 || $i == $count) echo '</tr>';

    $i++;
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation as to why the code is an improvement otherwise the OP won't be able to learn from their question :)

Comment: @Jaydp may i ask what i did wrong? I'd like to learn from my mistakes?

Comment: @sean you've got a loop inside a loop - It's like `for every car, for every car (again), show a row`

Comment: I sorta get that the `for` statement was causing the problem and I didnt see a way around it as I need to provide an increment for `$i`

Comment: Aha ok - a for loop isn't required to repeatedly increment something; a while loop can use e.g. `$i++` too (as it does in this answer)

Comment: For loops can also be written as a while loop instead - something like `for($i=0; $i<10;$i++){}` is the same as `$i=0; while($i<10){ ..do something here.. $i++;  }`

Comment: @Luke Briggs I'm guessing that `while` there is a search through the database and returning values i'm then saying `for $i` less than or equal to the number of rows to increase by an increment of one per entry with another `if`?

Comment: @LukeBriggs So in short if you want to have a single loop keep to one query towards the database? Busy implementing your Answer will upvote once done!

Comment: meant @jaydp Sorry, very tired

Comment: Kinda chuffed I got this far after 2 months and only had access to mostly dummies books and stack overflow! with limited internet access

Comment: @sean Yep, sort of! It can help a lot to visualise how code gets executed, but essentially if you want something to occur once for each result from a database (or from any set of results), then that's just one loop.

Comment: Also good naming of variables is hugely important, as well as wrapping up stuff that isn't very clear into something that is - E.g. rather than `$row`, call it `$car`. Maybe wrap up database calls into `$cars = $database->get_list('select * from stock where class="car"');` as you can then use `foreach($cars as $car){ ..runs this once per $car.. }`

Comment: That's PDO right? confuses me at the moment, I get the just of what you're saying though, you're absolutely right relational variable would help keep track of my functions, loops and queries

Comment: @sean - please check this link. It's explain all things how mysqli works
https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-select-query.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better use CSS rather than putting this kind of logic in your code. I've made a very simple example in the snippet below where I use DIVs to break new lines every 5 div elements, maybe this should give you some cues. 
If you want to split for every 5 elements, you should divide 100 / 5, then you find 20% for each div element, however, I put a border of 1px size, therefore, I rounded the value to 19%, because of this extra width, I hope it helps!
ps.: I think there's a better way to deal with this border seamlessly, without this workaround, I can't remember how I solved this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.container>div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 19%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div>teste</div>
        <div>teste1</div>
        <div>teste2</div>
        <div>teste3</div>
        <div>teste4</div>
        <div>teste5</div>
        <div>teste6</div>
        <div>teste7</div>
        <div>teste8</div>
        <div>teste9</div>
        <div>teste10</div>
        <div>teste11</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is actually very simple and explanatory thank you, I'll look more into manipulating items with CSS